# Custom Queries are not working in ReactiveCosmosRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a cosmos repository by extending ReactiveCosmosRepository.
existing methods like findById, save are working fine for me.
At the same time added methods like findByColumnName(String name) are failing (Without throwing any exception).

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-spring-data-cosmos</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-beta.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I tried [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-cosmos-db#prerequisites) to create a spring boot sample and also do it well. And I don't know how you created a method like "findByColumnName(String name)"; I think you can post your method in your question and it will be more straightforward.

From my research, Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB SDK 3.x.x supports @query annotation for defining custom queries! Maybe [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/how-to-guides-spring-data-cosmosdb#custom-query-execution) will help you.
[image]

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.Query;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.repository.CosmosRepository;

@Repository
public interface UserCosmosRepository extends CosmosRepository<User, String> {
    @Query(value = "select * from c where c.firstName =  @firstName")
    List<User> findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);
}

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Service
public class TestService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private UserCosmosRepository cosmosRepository;
    
    public void run(String... var1) throws Exception {
        repository.deleteAll().block();
        final User testUser = new User("1", "Tasha", "Calderon", "4567 Main St Buffalo, NY 98052");

        LOGGER.info("Saving user: {}", testUser);

        // Save the User class to Azure CosmosDB database.
        final Mono<User> saveUserMono = repository.save(testUser);

        final Flux<User> firstNameUserFlux = repository.findByFirstName("testFirstName");

        //  Nothing happens until we subscribe to these Monos.
        //  findById will not return the user as user is not present.
        final Mono<User> findByIdMono = repository.findById(testUser.getId());
        final User findByIdUser = findByIdMono.block();
        Assert.isNull(findByIdUser, "User must be null");

        final User savedUser = saveUserMono.block();
        Assert.state(savedUser != null, "Saved user must not be null");
        Assert.state(savedUser.getFirstName().equals(testUser.getFirstName()), "Saved user first name doesn't match");

        LOGGER.info("Saved user");

        firstNameUserFlux.collectList().block();

        final Optional<User> optionalUserResult = repository.findById(testUser.getId()).blockOptional();
        Assert.isTrue(optionalUserResult.isPresent(), "Cannot find user.");

        final User result = optionalUserResult.get();
        Assert.state(result.getFirstName().equals(testUser.getFirstName()), "query result firstName doesn't match!");
        Assert.state(result.getLastName().equals(testUser.getLastName()), "query result lastName doesn't match!");

        LOGGER.info("Found user by findById : {}", result);
        
        List<User> a = cosmosRepository.findByFirstName("Tasha");
        if(a.size()>0) {
            String id = a.get(0).getAddress();
            LOGGER.info("Found user by name : {}", id);
        }
    }
}
```